# Passing Python Script parameter from VBA

Tags: vba, python-2.7

I have the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub cmdLoadSalaries_Click()
    args = "C:\Users\Cole\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel.py " & Me.txtUrl
    Debug.Print args
    Call Shell("C:\python27\python.exe " & args)
End Sub
```

The script runs fine without the "Me.txtUrl" argument, but fails with it.

In the python script I set a variable to argv[1]
ie PassedVariable = str(sys.argv[1])

But the script fails to run.

Any help would be great, thanks all.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print args` give as output? Put differently - what happens if you "hard code" the string you think you are passing in `args`?

Comment: @Floris Fair question. 'C:\Users\Cole\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel.py http://www.fanduel.com/e/Game/NHL_Salary_Cap_7254/view?tableId=1474672&tableHash=ccbb5319be1a451a3f441195d26595f5)'

Comment: Have you tried quoting the arguments?

Comment: `C:\Users\Cole\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel.py 'http://www.fanduel.com/e/Game/NHL_Salary_Cap_7254/view?tableId=1474672&tableHash=ccbb5319be1a451a3f441195d26595f5'` Doesn't seem to work with this quoting, thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: so when I take the debug.print output and use it to "hard code" with in my python script (ie overwrite PassedVariable = str(sys.argv[1]) with `PassedVariable = 'http://www.fanduel.com/e/Game/NHL_Salary_Cap_7254/view?tableId=1474672&tableHash=ccbb5319be1a451a3f441195d26595f5'` The code runs fine

Comment: I think   @TimWilliams means the front part also need to be quoted, as there's space inside  "C:\Users\Cole\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel\pyFanDuel.py "

Comment: OK - so by the time Python consumes the string, it isn't what you thought. What, according to your script, is in sys.argv[1]?

Comment: Also note - I think in windows you must use double quote, not single quote...

Comment: Hey, it was the single quotes that did it, changing to doubles works. Whew. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Glad it worked. I was responding from my phone - could not confirm this was the right solution so put it as a comment. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to get credit for giving the "right" answer, I will repeat what I said above (and what you confirmed):
Put the argument in double quotes to "properly escape" all those strange characters as they are passed through the DOS shell.