# VBA running python script - Permission Error

Tags: python, excel, vba

So, i'm trying to run a Python code using VBA. Read a lot of similar topics here, but could not found an answer.

Every time i use the code below, CMD inform a Permission Error - image below.

The Python script run perfectly on manual click.

Any ideas on the matter?

**VBA CODE**

```
Dim obj As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim Script As String

Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Program Files (x86)"""

Script = "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\firsttry.py"

obj.Run "cmd /k cd /d" & PythonExe & "&& " & "python" & " " & Script
```

**PYTHON CODE**

```
# pip instal PyPDF2

import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


source_dir = os.getcwd()

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.startswith('Doc.'):
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=item, bookmark=None, pages=None)
           
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        merger.append(item)
    
merger.write('try.pdf')
merger.close()
```

**Erro - image and text**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z37a2.jpg)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\firsttry.py", line 19, in <module>
    merger.write('try.pdf')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 214, in write
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'try.pdf'
```

Comment: you've posted your VBA code twice....

Comment: Sorry buddy, edited.

Comment: `getcwd` might be a different directory when the script is called from VBA vs. when you run it directly.

Comment: **You are right!** I changed getcwd to **os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Capas geradas automaticamente')** and worked just fine.

If you could help me a bit more. Is possible to inform the path using vba? 

I though something like - import sys, and changing  source_dir to source_dir = sys.argv

Comment: You should be able to pass the path as a command line argument to your python script.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393182/passing-python-script-parameter-from-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, I think Im having a same problem but cant figure out how to change mine to os.chdir, Could you please take a look on mine ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055354/call-python-code-in-vba-permission-error/71056062#71056062

Comment: @Greencolor - sorry I'm OK in VBA but no idea about Python